# Metric Spaces : Help on a Simple misunderstanding please

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

so I've just started learning about metric spaces and as an exercise we've been tasked with proving that the euclidean metric on the reals is indeed a metric space. so here's where I'm at at the moment

> for $X \neq \emptyset$,  a mapping $d:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{0\geq}$ is called a metric on X if it follows the following axioms
>
> > (1): $(\forall(x,y) \in X \times X)[0 \leq d(x,y) < \infty]$
> >
> > (2): $(\forall(x,y) \in X \times X)[(d(x,y)=0) \Longleftrightarrow (x=y)]$
> >
> > (3): $(\forall(x,y) \in X \times X)[d(x,y)=d(y,x)]$
> >
> > (4): $(\forall(x,y,z) \in X \times X \times X)[d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)]$
>
> where (X,d) is called a metric space and d(x,y) is the distance between points x and y.

so in my case we want to show $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ is a metric space where 
$$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$$

quite a few of the lecture notes state that some of the example metrics obviously satisfy points 1-3 and i understand that they do (for example the above is obviously larger than 0 as we're taking the sum of real squares) but how do i go about proving its finite? i mean it seems obviously finite as the points can only take a single finite value from $\mathbb{R}$ and so the distance between two finite values is obviously finite. but again i feel that my examiner isn't (for the sake of the argument) going to accept "this is obviously finite"

for point two; we can set $(x_1=y_1),(x_2=y_2)$ in order to show that
$$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2} = 0$$ and then set $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2} = 0$$ to show that $(x_1=y_1),(x_2=y_2)$

for point 3: we note because of the squares it doesnt matter whether we add then minus or minus then add. it's strictly positive anyway further the reals are abelian. so in order to prove this i'd just pick two arbitary vectors and show it comes out the same (because of point 2)

for point 4: admittedly im still working on this bit but i'm told this is often the hardest part to prove.

so anyway, any and all help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I think everyone would agree that $d((x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2))$ is obviously finite. To prove 4, square both sides of the inequality $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z),$ and prove the squared inequality (which proves the original).

Comment: Yes, the part of proving a metric space that requires the effort is generally always the triangle inequality. Are you asking for hints on the triangle inequality, or just looking for feedback on the other parts?

Comment: Just to be explicit: because the product of two numbers is a number, the sum of two numbers is a number, and the square root of a non-negative number is a number.  "Number" in all cases meaning "finite number".

Comment: i agree, and i feel like i may be over thinking this (about point 1) in all honesty, but a nasty case of autism nags me that it's expected of me to know how to prove it regardless.

hence my problem, assume someone doesnt agree that its finite its now my burden to prove it is...

ok after the third comment i've come to the conclusion that i'm being stupid and i dont need to be that explicit. thank you guys for the hints and the comments i really appreciate it. i'll work on squaring both sides for part 4.

Comment: @Vaas I think you are not stupid at all. I have the feeling that you are on the right track. It is better to be like that.

Comment: @Vaas I think my comment about part 4 was misleading, I don't think squaring both sides make the problem that much easier... I apologize if I lead you down a frustrating path

Comment: Regarding "finiteness" : If $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 \in \Bbb R$, then is $\sqrt {(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}\;$ a member of  $\Bbb R$?